# Numerical Methods and MATLAB code

Tags: matlab

I am a self-learner of MATLAB. While reading some research papers and trying to implement them in MATLAB I am feeling a lot of difficulties.

The issue I feel is being unable to understand mathematical algos / notations and mapping it to MATLAB code.

Is there any reference / materials that describes Mathematical formulas / concept mapped to its implementation technique in Matlab.

A material that describes mathematics concepts like Algebra, Series, Calculus, Trigonometry etc so on with its implementation mechanism in MATLAB accordingly.

This would be a great boost to me.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is much too broad to be answered precisely. Could you distill it down to a concrete problem you are having? Otherwise, I assume you have already browsed the MATLAB Help Files? I found them very helpful in the beginning...

Comment: It feels like you are asking for a tutorial. I am afraid that is offtopic here.

Comment: Actually I was not searching for tutorials - but guidance from experienced people for the right advice based upon issues that I am facing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one of the MIT Open Courses ["Introduction to MATLAB"](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/#cat=engineering) could be quite exactly what you are looking for (currently there are 3 offered).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference. Thanks a lot

Comment: link is broken or course dne

Comment: @jeea: thanks for the info. I changed the link to the list of all engineering courses. The list currently offers three "Introduction to MATLAB" courses (2008, 2011 and 2019).

Answer (score 2):

Why not learn from "chef himself", Cleve Moler. He wrote various helpful guides. ["Numerical Computations with Matlab"](http://mathworks.de/moler/chapters.html) could be a good start. He formulates mathematical problems and translates them into Matlab language.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference and guidance